# Including a Compoment only After Lgin In yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

So I am trying to use the Admin Lte Package with Yii2 Basic. I have followed a few tutorials online on how to install it. It looks awesome after installation but I have a problem.
My Issue is that, I want this new View to work only when the user is authenticated else, it should follow the default Yii2 Application.
How do I condition this in the web.php or if there's another way out, I will like to know.

```
Config/web.php 
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                '@app/views' => '@vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app'
            ],
         ], 
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, you may create 2 entry points:

- `@app/web/index.php` (let's call it `main`)
- `@app/web/adminlte.php` (let's call it `adminlte`)

`index.php` will include its own config file (in which there is **no adminlte-implementation**).
`adminlte.php` will connect its config file (in which **has adminlte-implementation**).
Both entry points will trigger `Application::run()` to run Yii-applications.

Configure URL splitting on the web server side.
For example:

- `example.com` --> `index.php`
- `cp.example.com` --> `adminlte.php`

or

- `example.com/cp/` --> `adminlte.php`
- `example.com` --> `index.php`
  or in some other way that you like.

Plus, add redirects from one Application to another:
If the user opene URL based `adminlte` and he is not authorized, redirect him to `main`.
If the user opene URL based `main` and he is authorized, redirect him to `adminlte`.

As a result, you get 2 entry points (2 separate Yii applications).
But at the same time, they will be able to work without problems with the same database, and the same codebase (models, auth, etc).